# Add table column cells with input textbox and without

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding the values of a column in a table with the following javascript function:

```
function sumOfColumns(tableID, columnIndex, hasHeader) {
    var tot = 0;
    $("#" + tableID + " tr" + (hasHeader ? ":gt(0)" : ""))
    .children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")
    .each(function() {
        tot += $(this).html();
    });
    return tot;
}
```

I would like to modify it so it adds not only the numbers in the cell, but also include the value of textboxes in cells. A cell can either have a number or a textbox with a number.

The following cells should add up to 2115:

```
<table>
<tr><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="5" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>10</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" value="2000" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this most efficiently?
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function sumOfColumns(tableID, columnIndex, hasHeader) {
    var tot = 0;
    $("#" + tableID + " tr" + (hasHeader ? ":gt(0)" : ""))
    .children("td:nth-child(" + columnIndex + ")")
    .each(function() {
        tot += parseFloat($(this).text() || $('input:text', this).val());
    });
    return tot;
}
```

I substituted parseFloat() as you didn't include your fNum(text, bool) function.

Demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKovacs/hvBHq/